# Does Vue calculate nextTick when you await "anything" in a Jest test?

Tags: vue.js, events, async-await, jestjs

My example component shows a counter (initially "0") and an "increase" button. It looks something like this:

```
    <div ref="label">{{ counter }}</div>
    <div
        ref="button"
        @click="counter++"
    >
        Click me
    </div>
```

If I test the click behaviour with Jest the following test will fail

```
it('increases the counter when the button is clicked', async () => {
    const button = testComponent.findComponent({ ref: 'button' })
    button.vm.$emit('click');

    const label = testComponent.findComponent({ ref: 'label' })
    expect(label.text()).toBe('1'); // fails
});
```

As I understand correctly, the event handler is called synchronously but the DOM update is still waiting in the async update queue of Vue. So to make the test work, I have to await `Vue.$nextTick()` for the DOM to be updated:

```
it('increases the counter when the button is clicked', async () => {
    const button = testComponent.findComponent({ ref: 'button' })
    button.vm.$emit('click');

    await Vue.$nextTick();

    const label = testComponent.findComponent({ ref: 'label' })
    expect(label.text()).toBe('1'); // succeeds
});
```

But I can await *anything* for the DOM to be updated. I can literally await an empty object and the test will succeed:

```
it('increases the counter when the button is clicked', async () => {
    const button = testComponent.findComponent({ ref: 'button' })
    button.vm.$emit('click');

    await {};

    const label = testComponent.findComponent({ ref: 'label' })
    expect(label.text()).toBe('1'); // succeeds
});
```

I can't figure out why this is. Is it a specific behaviour of Jest? Why is this working?

Comment: Because awaiting *anything* yields control and lets the runtime evaluate stuff in the microtask queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await null` is a generic way to *wait a bit* until another promise that was created before settles, it works as intended only if another promise settles instantly:

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('foo'));
await null;
console.log('bar'); // output is foo bar
```

The [documentation](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-async-components.html#asynchronous-behavior-outside-of-vue) suggests to use `flush-promises` that [waits for a promise together with `setTimeout` or `setImmediate`](https://github.com/kentor/flush-promises/blob/master/index.js) and is a way to *wait a bit more*.

`nextTick` returns a promise that instantly resolves, so `await Vue.nextTick()` can be replaced with `await null`. It's unlikely that this will be changed in future Vue versions but if it will, this will break the code that uses `await null`. If a promise that can be awaited is accessible, like in case of `nextTick`, it's semantically correct to chain it, at least this explicitly specifies what we wait for.